# Is there a way to play poker in peace?

Tags: poker-night-2

In an attempt to go for the million dollar achievement, while it hurts to sit from how hard this game has been violating me, the most painful part is that it never gives me a moment's silence. The characters, especially GlaDOS, are constantly chattering and interrupting, preventing me from actually playing the game. The dialogue was entertaining once upon a time, but has grown increasingly repetitive. I recall from farming hands in the first Poker Night that right clicking the mouse would skip dialogue and that there was also an option to reduce the frequency of the chatting, but I am finding that neither of these seem to be available this time around. **Does there exist some way that I'm not finding to skip the talking so I can actually play the game?**

Comment: Mute is your friend? :p

Comment: Sadly, mute just leaves them talking in silence and still prevents me from playing during their dialogue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I feel your pain. It seems like the conversations in Poker Night 2 are not only more frequent, but far more *repetitive* than in the original; adding an additional character (GlaDOS) to the mix only increases the chatter.

Also, there's another unfortunate change that was made from Poker Night at the Inventory to Poker Night 2; there is no dialogue skipping during play ***or*** conversation frequency setting in the options menu. The best you can manage, sadly, is just muting the game.

***Disclaimer:*** I uninstalled this game a short while back, so it's entirely possibly, though unlikely, that they've patched the option in. I did some searching and people are still having the same complaint everywhere, leading me to believe this is still an issue.

Comment: I was just playing it and I could find no skip (hence the question) so I don't believe it was patched. I thought maybe I had missed something. Listening to them chatter is fine and there are certainly volume options for that if the noise were much of an issue, but the interruptions of play are the real pain. I can't even do other things on my machine while I wait for them to let me play again because the game pauses whenever it loses focus. I eventually found a save-scumming-like exploit to hold out for a winning hand so I just cheated to the $1 mil so I could be done with it.

Comment: Apparently, it is possible to skip the dialogue by clicking left and right click at the same time, as the answer below states. I can confirm this also works, since I tested this out myself.

Answer (score 1):

Right and left click at the same time skips the dialogue.